# How to test angular directive that is watching a function with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, directive

I have searched on the web for this, I found people testing watches of scope values, or triggering events like click.  but I haven't found something similar to what I have.  And I have tried a LOT of things..

My directive looks like this:

Note:  I am also using 'treecontrol' directive from angular.

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = [];

function myDirective () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs){
            $scope.$watch("selectedClass()", function(newValue){
                if( newValue !== ''){
                    subfunction();
                }
            });

            function subfunction(){
                // do things in here.
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive Tests', function() {

    describe('MyDirective', function() {

        var $scope, $compile, container, node, compiled, cNode;

        beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile');

            container = angular.element(
                '<div class="myclass">' +
                '<treecontrol>' +

                '</treecontrol>' +
                '</div>');
            compiled = $compile(container)($scope);
        }));

        it('should not do anything when selectedClass is empty', function() {
            node = angular.element('<div class="tree-label" ng-class="[selectedClass()]" my-directive></div>');

            cNode = $compile(node)($scope);
            compiled.find('ul').append(cNode); //compiling treenode adds a <ul> element.
            // treeScope holds the selectedClass() function
            var treeScope = compiled.find('treecontrol').isolateScope();
            treeScope.selectedClass = function(){return "";}; //attempt to override


            $scope.$digest();
        });
    });
});
```

Now, my problem, is that `$scope.disget()` or `.$apply(...)` triggers the directive, but the 'newValue' in the callback of the watch is always undefined, which means it goes into the 'subfunction'

Right now, what I am I trying to achieve is having the 'newValue' hold an empty string.

I have tried everything,  $timeout, .trigger(), .triggerHandler, spyOn, ...
I am out of idea, I don't know how to make something trigger the callback with a value.

The application is running this directive properly, when the selectedClass() is triggered on a node, it either call the callback with empty string (unselected) or 'tree-selected' for selected.

useless answer: check for newValue for undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got it.

```
    describe('myDirective', function() {

        var $scope, $compile, container, compiled;

        beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile');

            container = angular.element(
                '<div class="auto-scroll-container">' +
                    '<div id="test" my-directive ng-click="selectedClass()"></div>'+
                '</div>');
            compiled = $compile(container)($scope);
            $scope.selectedClass = function(){ return '';};
        }));

        it('should not do anything when selectedClass is empty', function() {
            var node = compiled.find('#test');
            node.triggerHandler('click');

            $scope.$digest();

        });

    });
});
```

I used a different approach.  I have put the `selectedClass()` watched from the directive in `ng-click`, and set the function on the scope. 
The click triggers the directive watch and the newValue contains the return value of the `selectedClass()` function.